# how to upload multiple files in spring

Tags: spring, multiple-file-upload

```
   <form action="upload" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input  name="images" type="file" id="input-file-max-fs" data-max-file-size="2M"  maxlength="35" disabled="disabled" multiple/>


    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitDetails" class="btn btn-success">save</button>

    </form>
```

i have done multiple upload of file but i am not satisfied with the view

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/2LLws/514/)

below is a fiddle in which i have to do

[link2](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/igniteuisamples/jsfiddle-samples/tree/master/EN/HtmlSamples/file-upload/multiple-upload/)

it is similar to gmail file upload.

but i am not getting how to do.

Comment: Neiter the first nor the second link work for me.

Comment: @sn42  i have edited my question

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is exactly. Can you please specify what the points are where you need help? Is it just the styling, the communication with the backend, ...?

Comment: my problem is when i select 2 files at a time it will display both files but i am not able to delete any one from selected . if i want to delete any one i need to delete both

Answer (score 0):

To clarify things a bit for other viewers: OP has an input of type file and wants to list the selected files beneath the input field. These already selected files have an "Remove Button" so a single file can be removed from the list of files to upload. Here is an image of what should be achieved (according to your 2nd fiddle):

[image: What should be achieved]

As far as i understand these functionality should be provided by using the  [jQuery Multifile Plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Files-multifile/jquery.multifile.js) from the 1st fiddle (and not using `igniteui` from the 2nd fiddle.

But if you select multiple files within a file dialog they are shown as "one entity" and not as multiple entities. This is shown here:

[image]

A note from the plugin's source code states:

> We do this in order to support `multiple` files. You can't display
>   them separately because they belong to only one file input.  It is
>   impossible to remove just one of the files.

I interpret this quote that it is not possible to split multiple files from one "input action" for this library. Am i wrong here?